# Avoid to print DEPRECATION msg on command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I hit `python -m pip freeze` command it shows below warning first and then shows package list.

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop sup port for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
```

Is there any way to ignore this warning?

I tried using `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` but it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```